# Помещение конфига в .txt в созданную папку (python)

Tags: python, python-3.7

Как поместить созданный .txt файл в определенную папку. Которая создается в этом же скрипте. Название папки меняется по дате.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
with open('devices.txt') as f:
     devices = f.read().splitlines()

for ip in devices:
    cisco_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': ip,
    'username': 'cisco',
    'password': 'cisco',
    'port': 22,
    'secret': 'cisco',
    'verbose': True

}
print('Connecting to' + ip)
connection = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)

print('Entering enable mode ...')
connection.enable()

output = connection.send_command('show run')
#print(output)

prompt = connection.find_prompt()
#print(prompt)
hostname = prompt[:-1]
#print(hostname)

import os
import datetime

_now = datetime.datetime.now()


# _today = str(_now.year) + '-' + str(_now.month) + '-' + str(_now.day)

def createFolderForTiff(folder_name, path):
    _fold_name = folder_names
    _path = path

    if not (os.path.exists(_path + '/' + _fold_name)):
        os.chdir(_path)
        os.mkdir(_fold_name)
    # else:
    # print('Папка с именем' + folder_names + 'уже существует')


folder_names = str(_now.year) + '-' + str(_now.month) + '-' + str(_now.day)

pathh = 'E:/back/'
for name in folder_names:
    createFolderForTiff(name, pathh)



now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)
file = today + '-' + hostname + '.txt'

with open(file, 'w') as backup:
    backup.write(output)
    print('Backup of' + hostname + 'completed successfuly')
    print('#' * 30)

connection.disconnect()
```

`

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Как создать папку? Как соединить имя папки и файла?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move - это если сначала создали файл, а потом хотите его переместить в созданную позже папку.